# raspberry PI not reachable from laptop intermittently

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to remotely gain access to the command line of a Raspberry Pi 3 from my windows laptop on the same network using ssh. I am using Putty as the tool.

Since both my laptop and Pi are connected using my home Internet wireless connection, they are on the same network. When I try to ping the Pi from my laptop, it says destination is not reachable. However, if I keep trying for 4-5 times, it finally works. I am able to use Putty and connect to my Pi and execute some commands. However, after few minutes, I lose the connection. When I try to ping the pi, I get the message destination is not reachable.

This issue is intermittent. I used the below link to set a static IP address.

http://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address-update

I am able to now always connect to my pi using a fixed IP address. However, the issue still exist. I am able to ping the pi after several attempts and then after few minutes the connection drops.

I am using the ADSL2+ internet connection at home and dont see any problem with that. In my Pi, I opened the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to confirm the port is 22. I use my Putty to connect to my Pi using port 22.

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: Do you have multiple routers or  WIFI access points at home? If yes, then check if there are multiple DHCP servers which conflict with each other. In a network only one DHCP server is allowed. Also check for duplicate static IP addresses. This will also cause continuously disconnects.

Comment: I do not have multiple routers or Wifi..

Comment: Try to change the ip address of your raspberry pi then. I think you have an IP conflict in your network with another device.

Comment: Just to eliminate other possibilities, I now switched to a wifi dongle. I can reach its page using IP - http://192.168.8.1/html/home.html. I used the link mentioned in the above post to change the static IP address of my Pi. As suggested by you, I have changed the IP to something different.

interface wlan0

static ip_address=192.168.8.200/24
static routers=192.168.8.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.8.1
Now when I try to find the IP of my Pi after a reboot it shows 192.168.8.200. I still have the same issue. Both my pi and laptop are connected to the same wifi dongle.

Comment: Just to add further, after few seconds I was able to ping my Pi from my laptop by trying to use ping 192.168.8.200. Similarly from my pi I was able to ping my laptop using its IP address 192.168.8.100. Very strange. AFter few seconds, I get message "Destination not reachable"

Comment: I am going to try to turn off the power management as suggested by few people. iwconfig wlan0 power off

Comment: OK. I think it works now. Looks like I had to turn off the power management. I will test and report if I continue to have any issues. For now, please consider this thread closed.